# Correct way to restyling a wordpress site

Tags: seo, wordpress, url, 301-redirect

I have a wordpress site that needs a complete restyling (both theme and urls).

I'm thinking about do the following steps:

1) Delete the current DB and WP installation on the domain

2) Install clean WP and DB, build the new site

3) Do 301 redirects from old urls to new urls

In a overall view, including seo, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry but the question is too broad and opinionated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct but make sure you do not skip (3). That is because if you do not redirect, as the old URLs reply with 404, they will quickly get demoted in ranks.... **However**, you can just install a new theme and go from there. I do *not* see a good reason to delete the Wordpress installation, even more the DB, unless it has somehow been modified along with the previous Wordpress installation core files.

Comment: I'd prefer a clean installion because the current installation is a mess

Comment: @Antonio102 I am not sure by what you mean "a mess" , I would consider messy if the core files have been changed . In any case , do whatever suits you just remember the 301 redirects. And if my answer is OK please remember to mark it as accepted.